# How to dispay previous orders made via PayPal for each customer

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

i am doing my graduation project e-commerce website http://www.fieldhockey-world.co.uk and i want the user to be able to see their previous orders made via PayPal. I manage to integrate PayPal but i am trying to create ***ForeignKey*** from ***users*** *table* to ***transactions*** *table* but i cant get the data because the users are redirected to PayPal website to purchase the goods. My database tables are as follow:
**TRANSACTIONS TABLE**

1. *id*    **int(11)**     PK
   *product_id_array*   **varchar(255)**
   *payer_email*   **varchar(255)**
   *first_name*    **varchar(255)**
   *last_name*     **varchar(255)**
   *payment_date*  **varchar(255)**
   *mc_gross*  **varchar(255)**
   *payment_currency*  **varchar(255)**
   *txn_id*    **varchar(255)** UNIQUE
   *receiver_email*    **varchar(255)**
   *payment_type*  **varchar(255)**
   *payment_status*    **varchar(255)**
   *txn_type*  **varchar(255)**
   *payer_status*  **varchar(255)**
   *address_street*    **varchar(255)**
   *address_city*  **varchar(255)**
   *address_state*     **varchar(255)**
   *address_zip*   **varchar(255)**
   *address_country*   **varchar(255)**
   *address_status*    **varchar(255)**
   *notify_version*    **varchar(255)**
   *verify_sign*   **varchar(255)**
   *payer_id*  **varchar(255)**
   *mc_currency*   **varchar(255)**
   *mc_fee*    **varchar(255)**

**

1. **USERS TABLE**

   *user_id*   **int(11)** PK
   *username*  **varchar(32)**
   *password*  **varchar(32)**
   *first_name*    **varchar(32)**
   *last_name*     **varchar(32)**
   *email*     **varchar(80)**     UNIQUE
   *email_code*    **varchar(32)**
   *active*    **int(11)**
   *type*  **int(11****)**
   *date_of_birth*     **date**
   *street_address*    **varchar(80)**
   *city*  **varchar(80)**
   *post_code*     **varchar(6)**

If you have any ideas please let me know. Thanks indeed!

**MY_IPN** code

```
<?php


// Check to see there are posted variables coming into the script
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST") die ("No Post Variables");
// Initialize the $req variable and add CMD key value pair
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
// Read the post from PayPal
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// Now Post all of that back to PayPal's server using curl, and validate everything with PayPal
// We will use CURL instead of PHP for this for a more universally operable script (fsockopen has issues on some environments)
//$url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$curl_result=$curl_err='';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Content-Length: " . strlen($req)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , 0);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$curl_result = @curl_exec($ch);
$curl_err = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$req = str_replace("&", "\n", $req);  // Make it a nice list in case we want to email it to ourselves for reporting

// Check that the result verifies
if (strpos($curl_result, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
    $req .= "\n\nPaypal Verified OK";
} else {
    $req .= "\n\nData NOT verified from Paypal!";
    mail("bogomilpavlov@yahoo.com", "IPN interaction not verified", "$req", "From: 
    bogomilpavlov@yahoo.com" );
    exit();
}

$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$custom = $_POST['custom'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
$mc_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['payment_currency'];
$payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$txn_type = $_POST['txn_type'];
$payer_status = $_POST['payer_status'];
$address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
$address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
$address_state = $_POST['address_state'];
$address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
$address_country = $_POST['address_country'];
$address_status = $_POST['address_status'];
$notify_version = $_POST['notify_version'];
$verify_sign = $_POST['verify_sign'];
$payer_id = $_POST['payer_id'];
$mc_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$mc_fee = $_POST['mc_fee']; 

// Place the transaction into the database
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactions (product_id_array, payer_email, first_name, last_name, payment_date, mc_gross, payment_currency, txn_id, receiver_email, payment_type, payment_status, txn_type, payer_status, address_street, address_city, address_state, address_zip, address_country, address_status, notify_version, verify_sign, payer_id, mc_currency, mc_fee) 
   VALUES('$custom','$payer_email','$first_name','$last_name','$payment_date','$mc_gross','$payment_currency','$txn_id','$receiver_email','$payment_type','$payment_status','$txn_type','$payer_status','$address_street','$address_city','$address_state','$address_zip','$address_country','$address_status','$notify_version','$verify_sign','$payer_id','$mc_currency','$mc_fee')") or die ("unable to execute the query");

mysql_close();
// Mail yourself the details
mail("bogomilpavlov93@gmail.com", "NORMAL IPN RESULT!", $req, "From: bogomilpavlov@yahoo.com");
?>
```

**CART** code

```
<?php 
// Connect to the MySQL database 
include("storescripts/init.php");
protect_page();
include("includes/template_head.php");


session_start(); // Start session first thing in script

// Script Error Reporting (cart error!!!!)
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors', '1');

?>
<?php 
//Section 1 (if user attempts to add something to the cart from the product page)
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $wasFound = false;
    $i = 0;
    // If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
    if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) { 
        // RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET
        $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
    } else {
        // RUN IF THE CART HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN IT
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
              $i++;
              while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                  if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $pid) {
                      // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                      array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1)));
                      $wasFound = true;
                  } // close if condition
              } // close while loop
           } // close foreach loop
           if ($wasFound == false) {
               array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
           }
    }
    //header("location: cart.php"); 

}
?>
<?php 
//Section 2 (if user chooses to empty their shopping cart)
if (isset($_GET['cmd']) && $_GET['cmd'] == "emptycart") {
    unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
}
?>
<?php 
//Section 3 (if user chooses to adjust item quantity)
if (isset($_POST['item_to_adjust']) && $_POST['item_to_adjust'] != "") {
    // execute some code
    $item_to_adjust = $_POST['item_to_adjust'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $quantity = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $quantity); // filter everything but numbers
    if ($quantity >= 100) { $quantity = 99; }
    if ($quantity < 1) { $quantity = 1; }
    if ($quantity == "") { $quantity = 1; }
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
              $i++;
              while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                  if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $item_to_adjust) {
                      // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                      array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $item_to_adjust, "quantity" => $quantity)));
                  } // close if condition
              } // close while loop
    } // close foreach loop
}
?>
<?php 
//Section 4 (if user wants to remove an item from cart)
if (isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove'] != "") {
    // Access the array and run code to remove that array index
    $key_to_remove = $_POST['index_to_remove'];
    if (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <= 1) {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    } else {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["$key_to_remove"]);
        sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    }
}
?>
<?php 
//Section 5  (render the cart for the user to view on the page)
$cartOutput = "";
$cartTotal = "";
global $cartTotal;
$pp_checkout_btn = '';
$product_id_array = '';
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    $cartOutput = "<h2 align='center'>Your shopping cart is empty</h2>";
} else {


    // Start the For Each loop
$pp_checkout_btn .= '<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="bogomilpavlov@yahoo.com">';
    $i = 0; 
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $product_name = $row["product_name"];
            $price = $row["price"];
            $details = $row["details"];
        }
        $pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];

        $cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;

        $pricetotal = money_format("%10.2n", $pricetotal);
        // dynamic checkout buttom assembly
        $x = $i + 1;
        $pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_' . $x . '" value="' . $product_name . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_' . $x . '" value="' . $price . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity_' . $x . '" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '">  ';
        // Create the product array variable
        $product_id_array .= "$item_id-".$each_item['quantity'].",";

        // Dynamic table row assembly
        $cartOutput .= "<tr>";
        $cartOutput .= '<td align="center" bgcolor="#F9F9F9"><a href="product.php?id=' . $item_id . '">' . $product_name . '</a><br /><img src="inventory_images/' . $item_id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name. '" width="100" height="80" border="1" align="center" /></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td bgcolor="#F9F9F9">' . $details . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td bgcolor="#F9F9F9">&pound;' . $price . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td bgcolor="#F9F9F9"><form action="cart.php" method="post">
        <input name="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" />
        <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="change" />
        <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
        </form></td>';
        ;
        $cartOutput .= '<td bgcolor="#F9F9F9">&pound;' . $pricetotal . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td bgcolor="#F9F9F9"><form action="cart.php" method="post"><input name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="X" /><input name="index_to_remove" type="hidden" value="' . $i . '" /></form></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '</tr>';
        $i++; 
    } 

    $cartTotal = money_format("%10.2n", $cartTotal);

    //finish paypal checkout system
    $pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $product_id_array . '">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://www.fieldhockey-world.co.uk/storescripts/my_ipn.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.fieldhockey-world.co.uk/checkout_complete.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to The Store">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://www.fieldhockey-world.co.uk/paypal_cancel.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but6.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal -     it\'s fast, free and secure!" >
    </form>';

}

?>
```

It is a bit long but this is what i have...

Comment: Side note, do you _realllly_ need a landing page?

Comment: What do you mean by landing page?

Comment: Just serve `home.php` right away instead of a landing page which requires the user to click to enter. Not only is this a better user experience, it is much better for search engines.

Comment: have you tried anything that you can show us?

Comment: These are my codes for the payment system.